# Using app name in angular js div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my html and angular js code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function DemoController($scope) {
            $scope.user = {
                dateOfBirth: new Date(1970, 0, 1)
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
        Date Of Birth:
        <my-datepicker type="text" ng-model="user.dateOfBirth" />
        <br>
        Current user's date of birth: <span id="dateOfBirthDisplay">{{user.dateOfBirth}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work and gives output

```
    Date Of Birth: 
    Current user's date of birth: {{user.dateOfBirth}}
```

But if i remove `="demo"` from `ng-app="demo"` in the div it works...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign a name to the `ng-app` directive, you essentially create a module with that name. In this module, you will then have to define your directives, services, filters and configurations.

In your case, when you assigned the name "demo", you created a module named "demo". Function `DemoController` now is no longer part of this module.

To use this function AND assign a module to your application, you need to use the following way of defining a controller:

```
var app = angular.module("demo", []);

app.controller('DemoController', [function () {
    //The body of demo controller
}]);
```

This way, the application knows which module's controller needs to be associated for the scope of the corresponding view.

EDIT: [The ng-app directive reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp)

Answer (score 1):

My solution works, try this : http://plnkr.co/edit/zwOKitT8wznO17yZfz15?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        Date Of Birth:
        <br>
        Current user's date of birth: <span id="dateOfBirthDisplay"><span ng-bind="user.dateOfBirth"></span></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If there is no value to the `ng-app` directive, you can simply use `ng-app` without the `ng-app=""` code...

Answer (score 0):

The value of `ng-app` attribute [defines](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) the application's [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) name. In your case that's "demo". While you haven't declared `DemoController` within the module "demo", using an [angular.module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) call, it isn't visible within your ng-app html, executed in the scope of "demo" module.

What will work for `ng-app="demo"` is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.user = {
            dateOfBirth: new Date(1970, 0, 1)
        }
    });
</script>
```